# SQL, where attribute in subquery if it return anything or else return everything

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add a condition(subquery) that basically would filter the output but incase the subquery does not return anything, I want this condition to be ignored somehow.

my main query is very long and complicated so I will try to give a simple example here.

```
set @userid := 55;

select project, userid 
from users_projects
where userid IN 
(select userid from activeusers)
AND
project IN (select userid from paidprojects where userid = @userid)
```

So if `select userid from paidprojects where userid = @userid` returns an empty output, I want this last condition to be ignored.

I tried this

```
set @userid := 55;

select project, userid 
from users_projects
where userid IN 
(select userid from activeusers)
AND
project IN (IF count(select userid from paidprojects where userid = @userid)>0, (select userid from paidprojects where userid = @userid), (select userid from activeusers))
```

but it's not working and I am getting syntax error:(

Comment: use left join instead of subquery.

Comment: Can you add some example data for that and the expected output

Comment: my main query is very long and complicated so I just gave this as a simple example. I guess it's a bad example.

Comment: No need to post the main query, just a sample data and your expected output to give us the general idea. Here, you can use this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=87921774a39a8881e7d8c5fccc20e4e8

Comment: By the way, you probably don't need all those tables. Instead you can just have two tables of `users` and `projects`. Both of this table can each have an additional column like `status` and you can populate that with values like `active`/`inactive` (users) and `paid`/`unpaid`(projects).

Comment: Why are you comparing `project` to `userid` in the final condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if select userid from paidprojects where userid = @userid returns an empty output, I want this last condition to be ignored.

That is, you want *only* paid projects if there are any.  Otherwise, you want all (unpaid) projects.

First, I assume that you want to compare **project**s in the last query not a **project** to a **user**.  That just seems broken.

An explicit way to write this logic is:

```
select up.project, up.userid
from users_projects up
where up.userid in (select au.userid from activeusers au) and
      (up.project in (select pp.project from paidproject pp where pp.userid = @userid) or
       not exists (select pp.project from paidproject pp where pp.userid = @userid)
      );
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you so much. I wish I could answer all people's questions but I could not because I am a dev and given these 2 queries without having full understanding of the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do that ?
Let me see if I understood
you have

### user

You’re users table

### project

Where yow projects are

### user_projects

I is guessing that’s an N to M

#### Question

Why do you have a

##### paidprojects table

That table can easily and should be a column on user_projects table as well as active users table that table can also be a column on users table is user active then true else false

Your problem can be solve by a simple left join

```sql
SELECT s.user_tbl_col, p.product _tbl_col
FROM users AS s
LEFT JOIN users_projects AS up ON u.id = up.userId
LEFT JOIN products AS p ON up.productID = p.id
```

If The user hadn’t buy none the users info would be the only data